# DateTime with same amounts of days for each month

Tags: c#, datetime

is there an easy way or a ready to go class for having a DateTime where every month has the same amount of days?
I'm writing a calculation tool for resource planning and we use a standard month, no leap years etc.

Update:
OK maybe I should have mentioned a little big detail - I tried going for 365/12 = 30,42days/month. I can't see that happening as I always run into trouble when for example trying to get the days from my ticks (division and 1.999999999 etc).

Comment: That totally depends on what you want to do with it. You didn't explain your problem, only your solution. You mean if you do `new YourMonth(2013, 04, 01).AddDays(25)`, it gives the first day of May because your months always are 25 days, for example?

Comment: Once you produce a clear specification of what you want, writing a class representing that should be trivial.

Comment: You'd have to start your own country first.

Answer (score 2):

In the financial markets, there are a lot of ways of counting the numbers of days in a year, the number of days in a month, etc.  A particular way is called a "day count convention", see e.g. [the wikipedia article on day count conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_count_convention).  One type of day count conventions tries to do exactly what you're talking about, namely have 30 days in each month.  These day count conventions are called 30/360, and as you can see from the wikipedia page there are several variations on this.  All these conventions are very straightforward to implement, so my suggestion would be to choose one of these day count conventions and code it yourself.